# AngularJS ngChange trigger onblur

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

for `ng-Change`, is there way to trigger it only when on `blur`?
Similar to jquery `on('change')`?

I am seeking for a pure `angular` way of doing this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Starting with [release 1.2.0rc1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120rc1-spooky-giraffe-2013-08-13) there is an `ng-blur` directive

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mvt8/6/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type='text' ng-blur='blurCount = blurCount + 1'/>

    <input type='text' ng-blur='blurCount = blurCount + 1' />

    blur count: {{blurCount}}
</div>
```

Script:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.blurCount = 0;
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}
```

Comment: this is not exactly what I want, if I didnt change the value but lose focus of that field, it will still trigger the function

Comment: You would handle that yourself in the blur handler.  If the value changes do what you need to, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: This official one will prevent the need to handle the change logic inside the blur handler: 
    <input type="text" ng-model="x" ng-change="onchange()" ng-model-options={updateOn: 'blur'}"/>

Comment: That is a much more elegant solution. It only works in v1.3 though (which is still in beta).

Answer (score 81):

Use [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

```
$scope.onchange = function () {}
```

```
<input type="text" ng-model="x" ng-change="onchange()" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"/>
```

Comment: Really saved time and this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ng-blur, and then (as Jason said) use the handler to check for input class="ng-dirty", that will tell you if the input value has changed.

Comment: ng-dirty is used for the whole form rather than just a input box.